# ruby array split at String

Tags: arrays, ruby, split

I have an array that looks like this...

```
array=["cab 3 > ", #<...>, #<...>, #<...>, "cab 2 > ", #<...>, #<...>, "cab 1 > ", #<...>]
```

I'd like to split it at every String to get this...

```
array=[["cab 3 > ", #<...>, #<...>, #<...>], ["cab 2 > ", #<...>, #<...>], ["cab 1 > ", #<...>]]
```

I tried... but can't figure it out

```
array.group_by{|name| p name.split(/""/)} 
array.group_by{|name| p name.split(/\"\"/)} 
array.group_by{|name| p name.split(String)}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, you want to create a new *slice* of the array before every `String`.

This can be achieved using the [`Enumerable#slice_before`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-slice_before) method:

```ruby
array.slice_before(String)
```

This will return an [`Enumerator`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerator.html) of the form you desire. If you absolutely need an [`Array`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html), then you can use the [`Enumerable#to_a`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-to_a) method:

```ruby
array.slice_before(String).to_a
#=> [["cab 3 > ", 1, 1, 1], ["cab 2 > ", 1, 1], ["cab 1 > ", 1]]
```

Comment: The second option did exactly what I needed... thanks

Comment: To my surprise, you could fine-tune this by writing `r = /\Acab \d+ > \z/; array.slice_before(r).to_a  => [["cab 3 > ", 1, 1, 1], ["cab 2 > ", "cat", 1], ["cab 1 > ", 1]]`. This works because `r === 1 #=> false`.